# Using .children() to get an <img> element

Tags: javascript, jquery, children

How do you use the `.children()` jQuery method to get an image element? Is it `.children('img')`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is. For example:

```
<div id="foo">
    <img id="image1" src="blah.jpg" />
    <img id="image2" src="blah.jpg" />
    <img id="image2" src="blah.jpg" />
</div>
```

You can get the images by `$("#foo").children("img")` if the images are *immediate children* of the `<div id="foo">`.

Another, more concise way would be `$("#foo > img")` -- it's identical to the above.

If the images are *descendants* but not immediate children of the list, you can use `$("#foo img")`.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that if you already have a reference to the parent element, you can use `$()` with a context. `$('img', ancestor)`. This way the `$()` doesn't need to re-evaluate the ancestors selector.

Comment: @xzyfer I'm pretty sure the selector with context argument is changed to `$(ancestor).find(selector)` internally.

Comment: @alex, I'm pretty sure that's only if the context isn't a jquery object already, otherwise it the following is executed `(context).find(selector);` (no `$`) so context isn't re-evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should...
http://jsfiddle.net/VvhCX/1/

Answer (score 0):

`.children('img')` can be used to get all children of an element with the tag `img`.
See the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/children/) for more detail.